# I would like to create an "or" relationship rather than "and" between the filters of my table in my Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jtable, filtering

I want to create an "or" relationship between these filters rather than an "and" relationship which is what this does. Is there any way to do this?

```
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(8);
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 1));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 2));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 3));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 4));
```

NEW CODE

try{

```
         List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(8);

         List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filter = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(4);
         filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 1));
         filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 2));
         filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 3));
         filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 4));

         RowFilter<Object,Object> orFilter = RowFilter.orFilter(filter);

         filters.add(orFilter);

         String gen = (String) searchGender.getSelectedItem();
            if(gen.equals("Male"))
                gen = "M";
            else
                gen = "F";

        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(gen, 5));
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchMailTxt.getText(), 6));
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchContactTxt.getText(), 7));
        filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchContactTxt.getText(), 8));

        rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);

    }catch(java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e){
        System.out.println("Unable to parse");
        return ;
    }
    sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`orFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#orFilter%28java.lang.Iterable%29) method:

```
filters.add(RowFilter.orFilter(Arrays.asList(new RowFilter[]{
  RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 1),
  RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 2),
  // .....
  })
));
```

But it seems that [`regexFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter%28java.lang.String,%20int...%29) can already accomodate multiple columns (I think just one of those needs to match, so that should have the same result here):

```
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(searchNameTxt.getText(), 1,2,3,4));
```

Comment: Both of these dont work, the first gives me the error, "The method orFilter(Iterable<? extends RowFilter<? super M,? super I>>) in the type RowFilter is not applicable for the arguments (RowFilter<Object,Object>)"

Comment: and the second also filters using the "and" relationship

Comment: updated the first example. It seems you need to wrap the filters into a list. For the second one: The Javadoc was a bit unclear. It says "Only entries with *at least one* matching value are included. " I took that to mean "or".

Comment: im still getting the same error unfortunately, so i tried to do this instead and now my filters arent working correctly. Can you spot the problem. See the updated code.